# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException

Tags: sql, asp.net, webforms, oledb, ms-access-2016

I am sending the following SQL query in MS Access 2016 as a string in ASP WebForm:

```
string showGridViewQuery = "select creditorName, amount, interestRate, interestType, interestCalculationMethod, insertedDate, o.fullName as owner, u.fullName as dataInsertedBy from tbl_savings s left join tbl_users o on ownerID = o.userID left join tbl_users u on dataEnteredByID = u.userID";
```

When I run, I get the following error:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'ownerID = o.userID left join tbl_users u on dataEnteredByID = u.userID'.

when the execution reaches `showGridViewCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` in the following code:

```
string connectionString = GetConnString();
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
con.Open();
string showGridViewQuery = "select creditorName, amount, interestRate, interestType, interestCalculationMethod, insertedDate, o.fullName as owner, u.fullName as dataInsertedBy from tbl_savings s left join tbl_users o on ownerID = o.userID left join tbl_users u on dataEnteredByID = u.userID";
OleDbCommand showGridViewCommand = new OleDbCommand(showGridViewQuery, con);
showGridViewCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter olda = new OleDbDataAdapter(showGridViewCommand);
olda.Fill(dt);
GridViewSavingsTracker.DataSource = dt;
GridViewSavingsTracker.DataBind();
con.Close();
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: what is your database management system, SQL Server, MySQL, MS Access, etc.?

Comment: I apologize, MS Access 2016 it is.

Comment: you are joining 2 times to tbl_users. Are you sure you need this? Could pls add table schema definition to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trails, I was able to come to the right solution:

```
string showGridViewQuery = "select savingsID, creditorName, amount, interestRate, interestType, interestCalculationMethod, insertedDate, o.fullName as owner, u.fullName as dataEnteredBy from ((tbl_savings as s) left join tbl_users as o on s.ownerID = o.userID) left join tbl_users as u on s.dataEnteredByID = u.userID";
```

I knew MS Access was bad. But didn't know it was THIS bad!